# How to add rgedit plugin to pluma?

Tags: 16.04, gedit, plugins

As most of you might know that in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS rgedit plugin does not work any more in gedit. Someone advised to downgrade gedit to version 3.10.4, but it didn't work for me, although the additional R menu and icons appear on menu bar. Some people advised to use pluma instead. Now the problem is how to add rgedit plugin to pluma? I have tried ".local/share/pluma/plugins" and other ways but no success at all. Has pluma its own plugin?